# .net application email solution?

Tags: .net, email

We need email server for our .net application below are requirements, all options i know of kind of blackbox which sends and receives email for accounts, working it through api is not much intended.

Basic requirement is send email + check status of email every 5 min to verify has it made it through.

Service requirement
-> Send email through .net api
-> When sending return identifier
-> Using identifier can check status

Any linux based solution should work fine as well for us, as long as it supports Rest to do above actions.

Answer (score 0):

.NET is fine for sending mail, using the [`SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class. However, checking for bounce messages requires POP3.

Having said that, POP3 is not a particularly complicated protocol, so you could roll your own client, or find an open-source implementation, such as [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/NetPopMimeClient.aspx).

*edit*

Taking a step back, the sort of notification you're looking for just isn't part of SMTP. Instead, the server queues up outgoing messages and sends them when it can -- which isn't necessarily within 5 minutes. If a send attempt fails, it will retry over the course of the next 4 days, with decreasing frequency. Only after that does it give up and toss a bounce message at the sender. If it succeeds, it doesn't send anything.

Now, there are various tweaks and settings, and perhaps some custom API's, but what you're looking for is not available out of the box.